# Why should I collect the bonus too?

Tags: team-fortress-2

There is a new gameplay element int Team Fortress 2 - Gun Mettle Update, so called contracts. I know that I can get 2 of them per week and I can collect weapons after completing the contract. But anyway, if you fulfilled the contract, in the end there is an optional "Bonus" which is harder to achieve than the normal contract.

I don't have any idea what this bonus looks like. I have achieved my contracts and I just traded them in after I had the bonus too. But it took a bit more time than the normal contract. Does anybody know whats the difference between a normal contract and a bonus contract? Is there a higher chance for better items or anything like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible to level the GunMettle Coin up to its highest level (Gold, requires 3000 contract points) without doing at least 14 of the bonuses completely out of the 26 contracts total.

No one knows what the benefit is for leveling up the coin.

Comment: Note: These numbers are assuming that Valve's "2 contracts per week" holds over the 13 week period.  As it is, it looks like it may be out of 28 contracts instead of 26, but at this point it isn't clear.  With 28 contracts, you'd only need full bonus points from 7 contracts.